# Is there a way to use model.predict() while calculating gradient?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm currently training a network for multi-image super resolution based on the RAMS network. I'm using a different, pre-trained model as my metric. In my training function I'm trying to calculate gradient:

```
def train_step(self, lr, hr, mask):
    lr = tf.cast(lr, tf.float32)
    
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        sr = self.checkpoint.model(lr, training=True)
        loss = self.loss(hr, sr, mask, self.image_hr_size)
        print(loss.shape)
        
    gradients = tape.gradient(
        loss, self.checkpoint.model.trainable_variables)
    self.checkpoint.optimizer.apply_gradients(
        zip(gradients, self.checkpoint.model.trainable_variables))
```

Inside loss() function I use model.predict() on batches of my data. I get an error:

```
LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'IteratorGetNext' (op type: IteratorGetNext)
```

In similar threads I found a suggestion to replace model.predict() with model() - the code runs, but it is very slow (6h per epoch).
Is there a way I can use model.predict() while calculating gradient or speed the process up in any way?

Comment: You already found the solution, to use model(),  there is literally no other way.

Comment: `the code runs, but it is very slow` -- probably because of the calculation of gradients ;)

Answer (score 2):

`predict` is for inference time, just do it how you are doing it in the  train loop by doing `loss(self.checkpoint.model(whatever, training=True), targets)`

About the *is slow*, that does not depend on the train loop, but is about your pc, the batch size, the model size, the data type and so on